# Convert BFR to PCAP without loosing nano-second resolution

Tags: wireshark, tcpdump

i have a BFR file from a customer that contains nano-second resolution. OI can convert it via tshark, but it does not retain the nano-second resolution on the end pcap file. Is there a way to convert BFR without loosing the nano-second resolution?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

I assume by "BFR file" you mean "file from Network Instruments Observer".

Pcap files, by default, support only microsecond resolution time stamps.  There's a modified version of pcap that supports nanosecond-resolution time stamps, but not all programs that can read pcap files will be able to read those files correctly.

If you're willing to have a file that not all programs could read, you could use `editcap` or `tshark` to convert the file and use the flag `-F nseclibpcap` to force `editcap` or `tshark` to write a nanosecond-resolution pcap file.

If `editcap` and `tshark` don't support that, you probably have a version of Wireshark that's too old, and will need to get a newer one.

Comment: Thanks, I did create the pcap using the "-F nseclibpcap" option and it does write to the nanosecond resolution, however, when I look at the pcap, I see many packets sharing the same nano-second timestamp, that is not the case on the BFR file.